# PercentSupportLibrary : Set percentage values in xml?

Tags: android, percent-support-library

I want to use different layout width ratios for larger tablet screens. Is there a way to set percentage based (fraction-type) values such as `layout_widthPercent` and `layout_marginStartPercent` in `dimens.xml`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just solved it. The values in `dimens.xml` will be something like this :

```
<resources>
    <item name="width_percent" type="dimen">60%</item>
</resources>
```

Comment: How can I get this value programatically ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if anyone else has had this problem since 2015 but, you can use a fraction tag:

```
    <fraction name="dialog_anim_y_scale">14.285571%</fraction>
```